# forEach works - why not for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the `flatten` kata at codewars.com - my code closely resembles a solution I've found, so I feel like my logic is on the right track. But I can't seem to get my code to work and I don't know if it's a dumb syntax error or if I'm doing something fundamentally incorrect.

Instructions:

```
Write a function that flattens an Array of Array objects into a flat Array. Your function     
must only do one level of flattening.

flatten([[1,2,3],["a","b","c"],[1,2,3]])  // => [1,2,3,"a","b","c",1,2,3]
```

Working solution using `forEach`:

```
var flatten = function (lol){
  var res = [];
  lol.forEach(function (x) {
    if (x instanceof Array)
      res = res.concat(x);
    else
      res.push(x);
  });

  return res;
}
```

My code using `for` loops:

```
var flatten = function (array){
  var newArray = [];  

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i instanceof Array)
      for (e = 0; e < i.length; e++) {
        newArray.push(e);
      }
    else
      newArray.push(i);
    }
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Look at `i = 0` and `i instanceof Array`... notice anything?

Comment: Yup, i = integer variable, and will never be an array (ironically i = the first letter of the word).

Comment: I changed the condition to `if (array[i] instanceof Array)` and the block to `newArray = newArray.concat(array[i]);` - I think that should do the trick, but it's still not being accepted.

Comment: You also check against `i.length` in your loop condition.

Answer (score 2):

The most important reason why it isn't working is that you are treating your indices (`i` and `e`) as if they were the actual array elements (hence, the sub Arrays themselves). `i` is not the actual array, and does not have any array properties. It is just a number.

Each element must be referenced via the `array[index]`, so in the case of the array argument, in the top loop, you would check `array[i]`, but most importantly, if it is not an array, that is what you would `push()`.

In your inner loop, you face a similar issue with `e`. However, you cannot simply do `array[e]` as the array you would be looking at would be `array[i]`. The proper way to address this is to make another variable for the array OR simply `array[i][e]`. Again, this is the value you would `push()`.

I understand that this answer is a little vague, but it is intentionally so, as this is obviously an assignment from which you are trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array[i] instanceof Array)
```

Your algorithm looks fine, but you are referencing a Number index where you mean to be referencing an array element. Fix this in 3 places and your code should work.

Comment: There's a little more to the fix than just this one line.  Neither of the statements with `.push()` in them in the second code block are correct either.

Comment: That's true... Hopefully he can figure the rest out.

Comment: So you're not going to provide a complete answer?

Comment: I believe it does answer the question, because if he fixes this and the identical errors on other lines, his code will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the value of the original array to push/concat into the new one. Also, you don't need to check the type, you can just concat everything:

```
var flatten = function (array) {
    var newArray = [];
    var arrayLength = array.length;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        newArray = newArray.concat(array[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Spoiler:

```
var flatten = function (array){
  var newArray = [];

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] instanceof Array)
      newArray = newArray.concat(array[i]);
    else
      newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Answers should be self contained without the need to visit a third-party site. If we were to simply view the text of your answer, there is no answer here. Please edit your answer to include the actual answer or risk downvotes/deletion.